# testcafe api testing using roles for authentication

Tags: amazon-cognito, testcafe

I've been able to use testcafe's `Roles` to authenticate for UI tests, but now I'm trying to write some API testing.  It seems that authenticated Roles is not supported with API testing (via `t.request`) b/c I'm noticing that the `authorization` header is not attached to the request when using `t.request` with a role.  Here's a code sample that I'm trying to get working but the `authorization` header is missing in the request when I inspect the request object in my server.  Any ideas if I need to do something different for authentication for API testing?

Btw, I'm using AWS Cognito for authentication in our login page.

```
fixture`api test`
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    // qaRole is defined separately, but it basically goes through our login screen
    // which makes authentication request to AWS Cognito
    await t.useRole(qaRole) 
  })

test('make api call', async t => {
  const result = await t.request({url: `/api/orders`})
  await t.expect(result.status).eql(200)
})
```

Comment: This looks like a bug. I recommend you open an issue in the [TestCafe repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml) with a detailed description and attach a test example there so that the TestCafe R&D team can reproduce the issue and research it.